# Running login mutation in utility function instead of component

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

This question is probably a sign of my misunderstanding of the philosophy of Apollo/React/GraphQL, but I'm a bit stuck here.

I am writing the authentication logic for my single page app. I have a backend with a GraphQL API that authenticates users by returning a JWT access/refresh token pair. So, to login, I need to send a mutation to the GraphQL endpoint from my app.

My frontend uses Apollo Client. Now I understand I can run a mutation with `useMutation`, I understand how this works. But I also know that React Hooks need to be specified at the top of a component. I could have this `useMutation` call in a login component, but this feels like bad encapsulation.

The problem is that I want to have a separate `login` utility function that takes a username and password, sends the login mutation request to the backend, and returns the response.

From my understanding, I cannot use `useMutation` here, as I'm not in a React component. I can of course write a `fetch` call myself:

```
export const login = (username, password) => {
    return fetch("/api", {
        method: "POST",
        ...
}
```

but this feels unclean when I'm working within the Apollo Client ecosystem. Am I missing something, should I just roll ahead with these manual fetch calls, or am I misunderstanding the whole philosophy here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you have access to an instance of `ApolloClient`, you can call the [mutate](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/core/ApolloClient/#ApolloClient.mutate) method on it directly. You can also pass the client in as a parameter, in which case you might find it helpful get the client instance through the [useApolloClient](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react/hooks/#useapolloclient) hook. Alternatively, you can just export the client and then import it directly inside your function. Whatever approach you take, just make sure you're using the same instance of `ApolloClient` that you use elsewhere in your app to ensure you're updating the correct cache.

```
const client = new ApolloClient({...})

...

const { data, errors } = await client.mutate({...})
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, this answers my question. I realize I have a few more things to figure out regarding the architecture of my app... Might post another somewhat broader question soon.